# In LDA,why same document content could assign different topic?

Tags: machine-learning, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I'm running LDA topic modelling on my corpus. In this corpus, there are numbers of documents with exactly the same content, and it is just one word. I understand each document could assign to different topics in different probability. But I think, in theory, if the content are the same for two documents, they should be assigned with exactly the same topic with same probability. However, what happen here, is the documents with same content be assigned with different topics. What is the way to avoid this? Should I change some setting of the parameters?

Comment: I guess document level Dirichlet prior will lead to this problem, due to the probablistic nature.